# How to detect current element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add an attribute `data-pic` via jquery to multiple img tags:

```
$('#description img').attr('data-pic', $(this).attr('src') )
```

but, `$(this).attr('src')` won't work. What I need is the src of the current element (img) I am working with.

Comment: Use `console.log(this);` and see what's displaying in the console./

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Better yet, use the debugger to see what's going on. No point in stumbling around in the dark with a `console.log` torch when you can *turn on the lights* with the debugger built into the browser.

Comment: Cannot use $(this).attr() on a list of items.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yea that's good too. Sometimes it's easier to use `debugger;` keyword as well. `:D`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a callback function to use the contextual `this` keyword.

```
$('#description img').attr('data-pic', function () {
  return $(this).attr('src');
} );
```

Comment: Or even `return this.getAttribute("src")` as there's really no need for a jQuery wrapper here. Or if it's okay to get the resolved value rather than relative, `return this.src;` :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agreed... `:D` The second one is easier, I am lazy. I'll use `this.src`! `:D`

Answer (score 4):

> I add the attribute data-pic via jquery to images (more than 1):

You need to use a loop on each image.

```
$('#description img').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('data-pic', $(this).attr('src') )
})
```

Comment: Doing it with `each` is *possible*, but inefficient; just use `attr`'s callback function.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use a direct loop with `each()`. This will give you the `this` reference within the handler function:

```
$('#description img').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-pic', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Alternatively you can provide a function to `attr()` which will work on each element instance:

```
$('#description img').attr('data-pic', function() {
  return $(this).attr('src');
});
```